# install the glibc into a separate directory, but the so is still linked into the sys so

Tags: glibc

I make and install the glibc into a separate directory using the following commands:

```
[root@yf-sdc-cf06 glibc]# pwd

/home/work/glibc
[root@yf-sdc-cf06 glibc]# /home/work/glibc-2.12.2/configure --prefix=/home/work/glibc 
[root@yf-sdc-cf06 glibc]# make
[root@yf-sdc-cf06 glibc]# make install
But
[root@yf-sdc-cf06 glibc]# ldd lib/libc.so.6
    /home/work/glibc/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fe7f6aba000)
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff6a7d4000)
why is the  lib/libc.so.6 linked into /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (the system's so) instead of the ld-linux-x86-64.so.2  that is generated by the install?
Any ideas? Thank you!
```

Answer (score 0):

The ldd searches the library path to find the right candidate of ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, please try to do the following things:
vim /etc/ld.so.conf 
add your lib into this file
ldconfig

You might see the new libc is using your ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

BTW:

Please make your question more readable for human.

Comment: I tried as you said, but doesn't work.   I changed /etc/ld.so.conf and add my lib, run ldconfig and remake, but ld-linux-x86-64.so.2  is still linked to  /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2